# Puppet rpm mirror server

Tags: centos, puppet, rpm, yum

I am trying to create a local mirror repository using Puppet and MREPO Puppet module (https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mrepo), however, the package MREPO cannot be found on CentOS 6.

Does anyone knows any other Puppet module which will help me create a RPM Mirroring server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mrepo](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/mrepo.html) is available in EPEL for CentOS 6.

Though tools like [Spacewalk](http://spacewalk.redhat.com/), [Katello](http://www.katello.org/) and [Pulp](http://www.pulpproject.org/) (as msuchy indicated) are all potential alternatives as well.

As is just running `createrepo` yourself.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers! I have decided on using a Puppet module which uses the createrepo package as it is the most up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be Puppet module? If not, then I suggest you to use: http://www.pulpproject.org/